# ESLint always complains of "Missing return type on function"

Tags: typescript, eslint

[image: complaint]

ESLint complains of "Missing return type on function" even though a return type is defined as far as I can tell.

What could cause this? Am I missing something or is ESLint missing something?

If I return something that doesn't fit the specified return type it complains both that the returned value is not assignable to type string AND that there is no return type:

[image]

But I guess only the first is coming from ESLint so that explains the contradiction there.

Anyway any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not just because you need a space after the colon, is it? i.e `const fn = (): string => 'foo'`

Comment: No it seems it was just some wrong state in VS Code handling some old ESLint output or something, I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was a problem between VS Code and ESLint, reloading the window fixed it (ctrl+shift+p > Developer: reload window)